# File not found before extracting docx file

Tags: php, file-upload, docx, text-extraction

I want to extract a docx after the user uploads i want to display the contents. But it seems that I don't know how to call it.. because it keeps displaying "FILE NOT FOUND".
Its displaying perfectly if I define:

```
$document = try.docx
```

So I know it can't call the uploaded file.  This is the source code:

```
<?php
include 'configure.php';

if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) 
{

$document = $_FILES ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];// here was the issue.. tried many way but still failed

function extracttext($filename) 
{
    $ext = explode('.', $filename);
    $ext=end ($ext);
    if($ext == 'docx')
    $dataFile = "word/document.xml";
    else
    $dataFile = "content.xml";    

    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    if (true === $zip->open($filename)) 
    {

        if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) 
        {
            $text = $zip->getFromIndex($index);

            $xml = new DOMDocument;
            $xml->loadXML($text, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

            return strip_tags($xml->saveXML());
        }

        $zip->close();
    }
    return "File not found";
}
echo extracttext($document);
}
?>
```

Comment: Not sure you can open temp files like this with ZipArchive. I think you should first move it to a real location on the filesystem, then open it with ZipArchive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']` does not contain the name of the document, it contains something like '/tmp/asdjashdkjashda' you have to use: `$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]` in order to extract the extension.

Your code does not work because you are extracting the extension from '/tmp/asdjashdkjashda' and is not 'docx' so you're allways looking for `$dataFile = "content.xml";`(that only works for odt files).

So, to get the extension use `['name']`, to open the zip use `['tmp_name']`:

```
$document_path = $_FILES ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
$document_name=$_FILES ['uploaded_file']['name'];

function extracttext($filename,$filepath){
    $ext = explode('.', $filename);
    [...]
    if (true === $zip->open($filepath)) 
    [...]
} 
echo extracttext($document_name,$document_path);
```

Comment: Or you can move the move the uploaded file to a other folder: `move_uploaded_file($document_path,'/path/to/other/folder/'.$document_name)` and use your function with the new path